# ERROR incompatible JVM . Uso Manjaro gnu/linux

Tags: manjaro

uso manjaro, gnu/linux y a la hora de abrir dbeaver me dice "incompatible JVM version 1.8.0_372 of the jvm is not suitable for this product. Version:17 or greater is required" ¿Que puedo hacer aqui?.

Ya instale java y ya lo actualize, sin embargo sigo presentando el mismo error.
También desinstale dbeaver y lo volvi a instalar pero igual me da el mismo error.
¿Alguien que le haya pasado y me quiera ayudar?

Comment: Hola chinaskidev, supongo que cuando dices "actualicé", te refieres a que instalaste la "**JVM 17**", si es así, abre la consola y ejecuta: **java -version** que te imprime?, sino, debes instalar la versión "**JVM 17**"o superior .

Comment: hola marce, gracias por responder... actualicé la JVM desde la consola y ya pude entrar.

Comment: Grande maestro!!